# How to create SQL Server database without initial catalog connection string C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database

How to connect to a SQL Server from C# without using an initial database to create databases that do not exist yet?

I can create a database from my code in the first time that user use my app.

Comment: You can specify `master` as your initial catalog, it's a built-in database that is used by SQL Server to store all the system-level information for a SQL Server system.

Comment: Also look at [Pool Fragmentation Due to Many Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling#pool-fragmentation-due-to-many-databases)

Answer (score -1):

You could use `dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();`
Reference :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/ensure-created#ensurecreated

Comment: That's assuming the OP is using Entity framework. This isn't stated anywhere in the question or its tags.

Answer (score -2):

Just use a connection string without specifying the database, like in this example for MS SQL server:

```
var user = "admin"; // from some safe place
var pwd = "1234"; // from some safe place
var connectionString = $"DRIVER={{SQL Server}};SERVER=localhost;UID={user};PWD={pwd};Trusted_Connection=True;";
```

Then just use SQL CREATE DATABASE ... in order to create the database (assuming the user has the corresponding administrative rights).

Comment: It is better to use a [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0).

Comment: Yes, but that was not the question. Question was not to include the database name in the connection string.